# Socket.io: Send message to a specific namespace with specific ID

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible to send a message to a socket with different namespace using their custom socket.id??. I'm using socket.io to create a chat and send private message.

I successfully manage to create a room and send a message to each other privately using

```
io.to(room).emit('chatMessage', from, message);
```

But I also want to send a message to sockets with different namespace using their ID like:

```
io.of('nameSpace').to(socket.id).emit('chatMessage', from, message);
```

I've tried different combination such as,

```
io.of('nameSpace').to(socket.id).emit('chatMessage', from, message);

io.of('nameSpace).sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('chatMessage', from, message);

io.to(users[socketid]).emit('chatMessage', from, message);

io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('chatMessage', from, message);
```

but it's not working. Is there other way to send a message to a specific client with different namespace? I'm using a combination of rooms and namespace.

NOTE: I'm using the string query that's equal to the name of the user as the name of my room.

Comment: i don't know what's "namespaces" on socket.io but i writen a code before to sending a emit to certain  user id on the server to redirect him to the game page to start the game using mysql and node.js and socket.io if you care i  can write it on answer i think the code will be usefull to explain how to save passport user id on socket.io and sending stuff to it if it on the page

Comment: Yo? did you used rooms to emit to a certain user id?

Comment: i saved the user id's on array on socket.io and on mysql  then i called it  without using rooms

Comment: What version of socket.io did you use? I already did save the id's to an array but what I need is to send/emit a message to a specific socket.id with a specific namespace. I'm using a combination of rooms and namespaces and I don't think array would be the solution. Thank you for responding.

Comment: `io.of('nameSpace').to(socket.id).emit(...)` should work, provided that `socket.id` has actually connected to that namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution works for multiple namespaces.
Assume we have two namespaces:

1. /v1
2. /v2, Socket ID: LOchCx6DZ8YwPVF8AAAv

Syntax for emitting a message from namespace-1 to namespace-2 is

```
io.of('/v2').to('/v2#LOchCx6DZ8YwPVF8AAAv').emit('message', 'Hello');
```